# Which way background drawable is drawn in ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-drawable

> By default, onDraw() isn't called for ViewGroup.

So I have a question: What happen when we set background drawable for the ViewGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onDraw() is inherited from View class since ViewGroup is subclass of View. So when you set Background on a ViewGroup, it works the same way as any other view. When you call setBackground on a view, it sets *requestLayout* flag to true and invalidates the view.

Also, Official documentation for View class states that:

> If you set a background drawable for a View, then the View will draw
>   it before calling back to its onDraw() method.

You can see how it works in the source code of Android's View class

```
    public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
        ...
        {
            requestLayout = true;
        }
        ...
        computeOpaqueFlags();
        if (requestLayout) {
            requestLayout();
        }
        mBackgroundSizeChanged = true;
        invalidate(true);
    }
```

If you look at documentation for *invalidate()*, you will find

> public void invalidate () Invalidate the whole view. If the view is
>   visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point
>   in the future.

*setBackgroundColor()* and *setBackgroundResource()* use setBackgroundDrawable() internally so they work the same way.

So to sum it up, onDraw is called at some point in future when you do *setBackground()*.